# ASP.NET Core Identity, creating a Login, Register actions. AuthController

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager { get; }
    UserManager<AppUser> _userManager { get; }
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager { get; }

    public AuthController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, 
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager, 
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string? returnUrl,LoginVM vm)
    {
        AppUser user;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        if (vm.UsernameOrEmail.Contains("@"))
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.UsernameOrEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(vm.UsernameOrEmail);
        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password is wrong");
            return View(vm);
        }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, vm.Password, vm.IsRemember, true);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Too many attempts wait until " + DateTime.Parse(user.LockoutEnd.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm"));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password is wrong");
            }

            return View(vm);
        }

        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        var user = new AppUser
        {
            Fullname = vm.Fullname,
            Email = vm.Email,
            UserName = vm.Username
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, vm.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }

            return View(vm);
        }

        var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Roles.Member.ToString());

        if (!roleResult.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong. Please contact admin");
            return View(vm);
        }

        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateRoles()
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles)))
        {
            if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item.ToString()))
            {
                var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = item.ToString()
                });

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, I'm messing around with login, register, and logout in my code, and now this `RoleManager` thing is making me scratch my head. I'm just trying to hook up my admin user with some extra powers, but I'm a bit lost on what to do. If you can help me out by explaining the steps or what changes to make in simple words, that'd be awesome.

I'm aiming to make the admin user experience better in my system, and your advice on this would be really useful. Trying to understand `RoleManager` and how to give more abilities to my admin user. Your straightforward help could make a big difference for me in figuring this out!

Answer (score 1):

1. Define Admin Role
2. Create Admin User
3. Update Registration Process:

   var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, vm.IsAdmin ?
   Roles.Admin.ToString() : Roles.Member.ToString());
4. Use the Admin Role:

   [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
   public IActionResult AdminDashboard()
   {
   // Admin-specific logic
   }
   5.Enhance Admin Abilities:

   if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
   {
   // Admin-specific logic
   }
5. Middleware Configuration:

   services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddRoles()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores();
   7.CreateRoles Method:

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
   // Other middleware configuration

   ```
   // Create roles during application startup
   var authController = new AuthController(/* inject your dependencies here */);
   authController.CreateRoles().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ```

   }